# Resharper Power toy Zen Coding

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, emmet

I have tried the [ReSharper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReSharper) Power toy [Zen Coding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zen_Coding) and found it can only generate code in one line. Can it generate formatted code?

For example, I type in

**ul>li*3**

It generates:

`<ul><li></li><li></li><li></li></ul>`

I want it formatted as:

```
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What build are you using? I don't seem to have that formatting problem.

Comment: Got the same problem, build 1628.

Comment: I have the same problem with VS 10.0.30319.1, ReSharper 5.1.1751.8, but I'm not sure which build of the ZenCoding plugin. It's the release that's up on codeplex right now for R# 5.1.1 says that it was put there on Sep 24, 2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is also another Zen Coding Visual Studio plugin available at http://tech.einaregilsson.com/2009/11/12/zen-coding-visual-studio-addin/ which inserts formatted HTML by default.

Comment: This one is better, I can use it define my own snippets.

Answer (score 1):

I just found the shortcut key combination,

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>

for formatting selected HTML in Visual Studio.

Comment: cntrl-k, cntrl-d  for document might be easier for you.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested in VS2010 and zen coding, it looks like the most actively maintained project (as of this writing) is [here](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/924090a6-1177-4e81-96a3-e929d7193130).  Created by Danny_Su.  Find it in the gallery by searching for `Visual Studio Zen Coding 2010`